¿Cómo remover duplicados de consulta SQL?
Estoy practicando sql, me hice una base de datos, dejo el esquema

Cuando quiero seleccionar toda la información de ejemplo todo va bien, pero cuando hago la unión de las dos ultimas tablas se me duplica la información, ejeplo del query:
SELECT 
CAMP.nombre_campeonato
,EQUIP.nombre_equipo
,ESTAD.nombre_estadio, ESTAD.ubicacion_estadio
,JUG.cedula_jugador, JUG.nombre_jugador, JUG.primer_apellido_jugador, JUG.segundo_apellido_jugador
,PIE_JUG.descripcion_pie
,POS_JUG.descripcion_posicion_jugador
,EQUI_STAFF.cedula_staff, EQUI_STAFF.nombre_staff, EQUI_STAFF.primer_apellido_staff, EQUI_STAFF.segundo_apellido_staff
,STAF_POS.descripcion_staff
FROM [campeonatos] CAMP
    LEFT JOIN campeonato_equipos CAMP_EQUIP ON CAMP.id_campeonato = CAMP_EQUIP.id_campeonato
    LEFT JOIN equipos EQUIP ON CAMP_EQUIP.id_equipo = EQUIP.id_equipo
    LEFT JOIN estadios ESTAD ON ESTAD.id_estadio = EQUIP.id_estadio
    LEFT JOIN jugadores JUG ON JUG.id_equipo = EQUIP.id_equipo
    LEFT JOIN pie_jugadores PIE_JUG ON PIE_JUG.id_pie_jugador = JUG.id_pie_jugador
    LEFT JOIN posicion_jugadores POS_JUG ON POS_JUG.id_posicion_jugador = JUG.id_posicion_jugador
    LEFT JOIN equipo_staffs EQUI_STAFF ON EQUI_STAFF.id_equipo = EQUIP.id_equipo  -- Hace que se duplique
    LEFT JOIN staff_posiciones STAF_POS ON STAF_POS.id_posicion_staff = EQUI_STAFF.id_posicion_staff -- Hace que se duplique

WHERE 
CAMP.id_campeonato = 1

Resultado:


No veo ninguna duplicación. Todas las filas del resultado son distintas. No hay duplicados. Si te refieres a tener los datos de los jugadores duplicados, esto es porque hay un join de jugadores con los staffs que no son relacionados. Si un equipo tiene diez jugadores y cinco staffs, recibes 10 x 5 = 50 filas para este equipo.

A primera vista los datos no están duplicados, pero ¿qué esperarías obtener como resultado?
